# How to add an event at mutiple elements in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom, dom-events

I am trying to add an double click event at multiple elements in vue3.

I wanted to make a table list of contents data and add double click event on checkbox and favorite icon without using @dblclick="". it's because that it's easier to give a class name and add an event by class name with JS than put @dblclick="" every elements.

here is my ContentList component of vue

```
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <ContentListItem v-for="(content, key) in contentList">
</tbody>
```

I created a contentListItem component that contains content data and rendered in v-for.

here is ContentListItem code

```
<tr>
  <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
  <td>
    <!-- checkbox -->
    <input 
    type="checkbox"
    class="none-dblclick"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <!-- favorite icon -->
    <span>
      <svg
      class="none-dblclick"
      >
        <path ... />
      </svg>
    </span>
  </td>
  <td>{{content.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

If it was a pure HTML and JS, i would code like

```
const actionElements = document.getElementsByClassName('none-dbclk');
Array.from(actionElements).forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener('dblclick',function(e) {...})
}
```

But in vue.js i only found a way to add @dblclick="" at every elements in vue template.
additionally I've also heard that DOM mainpulation is not generally recommanded in vue.js

what else i can try for this case?

Comment: usually, in vue, if I have multiple elements like that, I'd turn them into a component - without *actual code* though, it's a bit hard to know if that would be appropriate in your case

Comment: Search for "vue3 dynamic listeners". In any case, you don't share your Vue code so we don't know what's going on. Are these elements rendered in a `v-for`? If so you can just apply `@dblclick=""` to each generated child, no? What's the problem exactly? Are these non-Vue elements in the DOM that you're trying to target? Then you would best use plain JS to target them.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I struggle a bit with seeing the issue with redeclaring code, as you present only two  elements where you need this functionality. And it seems tidy to present the `@dblClick` event wherever you actually have it.

However, f you can resolve the double click function for all events in a single generic component and want to avoid re-declaring, I'd suggest something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
  <DoubleClickTableCellComponent>
    <!-- checkbox -->
    <CheckboxComponent/>
  </DoubleClickTableCellComponent>
  <DoubleClickTableCellComponent>
    <!-- favorite icon -->
    <FavouriteComponent/>
  </DoubleClickTableCellComponent>
  <DoubleClickTableCellComponent>
    <!-- favorite icon -->
    <AnyOtherDblClickComponent/>
  </DoubleClickTableCellComponent>
  // ...
  <td>{{content.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Where this is pseudocode for DoubleClickTableCellComponent.vue:

```
<template>
    <td @dblClick="() => onDblClick()">
        <slot />
    </td>
</template>
<script>
//...
const onDblClick = () => {
   // Code here
};
```

However, if you need an individual implementation of `@dblClick` for each cell, I would catch and handle the event in the actual cells.